# Laravel using basic.auth access_token

Tags: laravel

i am follow laravel documentation about Basic Authentication
i already create an API who response

```
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 31536000,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9"
```

and i use the `access_token` on postman as

```
Header
Authentication : Bearer {{access_token}}
```

and set my route with `Route()->middlewire(auth.basic)`

the response always

```
{
    "message": "Invalid credentials.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\UnauthorizedHttpException",
...
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out 
i did not read the right documentation

I read basic auth documentation on laravel but actually I use basic auth with passport and on passport the middleware is not `auth.basic` but `client`, now i can use the return `access_token`